# WPF Listview selecteditem is not being typecast from sender as ListViewItem

Tags: c#, wpf

I've been working on learning WPF by writing a new app using it.  I ran into an issue with ListView so I created a new project with a single ListView to validate my issue.

I've been working off this site as simple example of my issue:  https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-with-gridview/ but I'll repost the code here.

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="ListviewTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ListviewTest"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <ListView Margin="10" Name="lvUsers" PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="lvUsers_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Age" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Age}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Mail" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Mail}" />
            </GridView>
        
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

CS

```
namespace ListviewTest
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<User> items = new List<User>();
        items.Add(new User() { Name = "John Doe", Age = 42, Mail = "john@doe-family.com" });
        items.Add(new User() { Name = "Jane Doe", Age = 39, Mail = "jane@doe-family.com" });
        items.Add(new User() { Name = "Sammy Doe", Age = 7, Mail = "sammy.doe@gmail.com" });
        lvUsers.ItemsSource = items;
    }

    private void lvUsers_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = sender as ListViewItem;
        if (item != null)
        { 
        
        }
    }
}

public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }

    public string Mail { get; set; }
}
}
```

The PreviewMouseEventUp fires and ends up on the method to handle the above event.

I set a breakpoint on

```
        if (item != null)
```

and item is null when I clicked on an item in the list.

The sender has the value but the typecasted variable "item" does not.

```
        var item = sender as ListViewItem;
```

Is not getting set.

This is a brand new project only for testing the ListView to verify it's not in my original code.  Does anyone have any idea on what is going on?

---

Comment: There is `<ListView ... PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="lvUsers_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp">` so the sender is obviously the ListView. It's unclear why you think it should be  ListViewItem. In order to get the selected item, use `var user = (User)lvUsers.SelectedItem;`

Comment: That was it.  Every example I had viewed including this one and numerous ones on SO were using ListViewItem.

Comment: An appropriate event to react on would be the SelectionChanged event - instead of any mouse event.